# Quantifiers and the meaning of the statement

Tags: logic, notation, first-order-logic, quantifiers

There's two statements:

(i) ∃x (PresentKingFrance(x) → Bald(x));
(ii) ∃x (PresentKingFrance(x)) → ∃x (PresentKingFrance(x) ∧ Bald(x)).

I'm not an expert in FOL, but I still understand a little bit. A little bit, but not this.

What's the difference between these two statements? Can you explain this to me with details by the means of natural language? Or maybe even graphically....

I also don't understand why can't we transform (ii) into ∃x(PresentKingFrance(x) → (PresentKingFrance(x) ∧ Bald(x)))

Answer (score 1):

If two formulas seem confusingly similar like $i$ and $ii$, then you can always take their negations and compare to see if they’re actually logically equivalent.

In this case, the negation of $i$ is saying *everyone* is a non-bald present King of France, while the negation of $ii$ is saying that there is a present King of France, and whoever is the present King of France is not bald.

These are clearly different, since the negation of $ii$ is not saying that everyone is a present King of France, while the negation of $i$ is. This is reflected in the non-negated versions, namely since $i$ is satisfied if just one person is not the present King of France, while $ii$ is not necessarily satisfied under those same conditions.

Also, note that the formula you mention in your final paragraph is indeed equivalent to $i$ since

$A \to B$

and

$A \to (A \land B)$

are logically equivalent.

Comment: I'm new in FOL, so I wanna ask for more detailed info about negation. Can you show me step-by-step negation of I and ii?

Comment: @ЕгорГалыкин all you need to know is that $\neg \exists x A \leftrightarrow \forall x \neg A$ and $\neg (A \to B) \leftrightarrow (A \land \neg B)$ are logical equivalences regarding negating existential quantifiers and implications for any well-formed-formulas $A,B$.

Comment: But what should I do if there's a few quantifiers, not just one (like in ii)? Should I just negate each part which is "bound" by quantifier separately? Can you show me this on the example of ii? It's the last question, I promise

Comment: @ЕгорГалыкин I’ll show you the first step for $ii$: $\neg (\exists x Px \to \exists x (Px \land Bx)) \leftrightarrow (\exists x Px \land \neg \exists x (Px \land Bx))$.

Comment: I understand now. Would the original (ii) be satisfied if there were for example four kings of France but only three of them were balt? This question is honestly last.

Comment: @ЕгорГалыкин yes, since that satisfies the consequent of $ii$, which is enough to satisfy the whole implication.